# Call shell script with argument in Mac application

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, shell

I'm having trouble calling a shell script which takes an argument from my Cocoa application for Mac.

I have created the shell script, and put it in the app's local repository. It is called SCRIPT. It takes one argument which is a URL address.

I call the script as follows but nothing happens, no errors or messages, just the script stops after doing nothing.

```
NSString *address = [_addressField stringValue];
NSString *resPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];

NSTask *task;
task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/SCRIPT", resPath]];

NSArray *arguments;
arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: address, nil];
[task setArguments: arguments];

NSPipe *pipe;
pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
[task setStandardOutput: pipe];

NSFileHandle *file;
file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];

[task launch];

NSData *data;
data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];

NSString *status;
status = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog (@"%@", status);
```

Thanks in advance everyone

Answer (score 0):

The Objective-C code seams to work fine for me if i try with `/bin/echo` as launch path. So i guess the problem is with the script. Can you include the script in your question? note that the environment when running from a Cocoa application is probably quite different from when running in a interactive shell.

Comment: I think the problem is that th script calls files on the computer, maybe in the cocoa app it's not finding them?

Comment: You need to provide more information about the script if people should be able to help you.

Comment: The script just downloads a file from the Internet using a shell builtin, then converts it using ffmpeg, and then moves it with mv to the user's home directory

Comment: You don't want to upload it somewhere like a pastebin? it's impossible to help you otherwise as the problem is most probably with your script. If you don't want to upload it could only give generic shell scripting debug tips like `set -x` at the top of the script, dump env to a file at start (look at PATH, PWD, library stuff etc), `echo "before ffmpeg" >> /tmp/log` etc, use `fileHandleWithStandardError` to read stderr or use a wrapper script that does `/path/to/actual/script 2>&1`

Comment: thanks Mattias but I don't believe the problem is with the script, it works perfectly if used outside of the Cocoa application, this is why I'm not posting it, if absolutely necessary I will but I believe it's a problem with the Mac app

Comment: Yeah but your Cocoa code works, it will start the script but i said previously running a program from a Cocoa application (which forks and executes it) will run in a quite different environment compared to running from a interactive shell. So to get this to work i think you need to add some debugging to your script and executing from the Cocoa application and see how it behaves. My first guess would be that some program used by the script (curl, ffmpeg etc) is not in PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a permissions issue? Try invoking /bin/sh and setting the script path as the first argument.